# How to set Appium --no-reset flag programmatically for AWS-Device Farm

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, appium, aws-device-farm

I want to set Appium Flag --no-reset programmatically.

---

This Flag is used when we don't want to reset app state between sessions (IOS: don’t delete app plist files; Android: don’t uninstall app before new session).
Its default Value is False, I want to make it true because I have written my Test scripts by making --no-reset=true on my local env..

---

**Why I want to do this**

I'm using AWS-Device Farm (which runs Test cases on multiple real devices using cloud service) to test my Android App and I don't have control over Appium server running on AWS, and by default its --no-reset flag is false ,Hence It resets my App during each run, Which results in Test Case Fail.

---

**Logs from AWS-Device Farm**

```
Starting testBBB
Pre-launching app
Starting android appium
Java version is: 1.7.0_75
Retrieving device
Found device 06db10920b305807
Device API level is: 21
App is already installed, resetting app
Starting App
```

---

Note:- I'm using Appium V1.4.6, Intellij Idea (Java), Junit Framework. Please Help And suggest some solution. Thanking You.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use --no-reset with AWS Device Farm cloud. Actually all devices from aws clod are dynamically allocated and reset every thing (i.e. apps+ data + settings) on each test run, according the AWS devicefarm design.

So every time you get a device it is like a fresh new device with all default settings.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure this functionality using the `noReset` desired capability when connecting to the Appium server.

Per the Appium documentation (found [here](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#appium-server-capabilities)):

`noReset  Don’t reset app state before this session. Default false    true, false`

Comment: I'v already tried that, but the thing is that AWS-Farm just ignores that Capability. I think that AWS Farm is in initial stage and there are many Flaws they might fix in next release. Thanks for your suggestion.